# Multiple session windows of a single key

Tags: java, stream, apache-flink, flink-streaming, windowing

I am struggling to implement a specific custom window in flink. The problem goes like that:
I have a keyed-stream by a certain id. For each new element in the stream, I need to hold multiple "session windows" for each id. For each upcoming element, I need to determine whether or not the element belongs to a certain session window and if it doesn't belong to any open session window, I need to create a new one. The belonging to a session window is dynamic and affected by the already open session windows, and can not be determined beforehand, like an additional 'key-by'.
Anyone has an idea how something like that can be implemented ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Flink' session windows are based on an abstraction of *merging* windows. Each new event is initially placed in its own singleton session window, and then all overlapping windows/sessions are merged. I think what you would need to do is to extend the `EventTimeSessionWindows` window assigner (assuming these are event-time windows you are working with) and override its `mergeWindows` method. You'll need to study `TimeWindow#mergeWindows` and figure out how to adapt it to meet your needs.

Alternatively, you could go a level deeper in the DataStream Window API and use a GlobalWindow with a custom Trigger and Evictor, but I think that's likely to get pretty messy.

Another alternative would be to go down yet another level in the API stack and implement your own windowing with a process function. There's [an example showing how to re-implement tumbling windows with a KeyedProcessFunction](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/event_driven/) in the Flink docs. While this approach is sometimes a good idea, handling session windows in this way might be challenging.